# Get value of object inside object angular

Tags: arrays, angular, object, angular-reactive-forms

I know there is a lot of similar topics, I just went thru all them and still do not understand what Am I making wrong.

I get the data from DEXIE(indexedDB) where my record is stored like this:

```
    async addRequestToLocalDb(request: Request, user: User[]) {

    this.db.requests.add({
        uuid: request.uuid,
        issue: request.issue,
        place: request.place,
        building: request.building,
        floor: request.floor,
        room: request.room,
        description: request.description,
        heading: request.heading,
        user: user,
        status: 'pending',
        date: new Date(Date.now()),
    });
    
  
    return await new Request('','','','','','','','','', user , new Date() );


}
```

Here is my template:

```
     <div [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" >

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size-md="8" push-md="2"
      ><ion-text class="ion-padding"><b>Kurztext:</b></ion-text></ion-col
    >
  </ion-row>
      <ion-item class="ion-align-self-end" lines="none">
          <ion-label fixed class="fixedLabel">Vorname:</ion-label>
          <ion-input
            required
            readonly
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="name"
            color="medium"
            style="
              border-width: 1px;
              border-color: #bbbbbb;
              border: 1px;
              border-style: solid;
            "
          ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item class="ion-align-self-end" lines="none">
          <ion-label fixed class="fixedLabel">Name:</ion-label>
          <ion-input
            required
            readonly
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="surname"
            color="medium"
            style="
              border-width: 1px;
              border-color: #bbbbbb;
              border: 1px;
              border-style: solid;
            "
          ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
```

I call this function from place of form:

```
     onAddRequest() {
    const currentUser = [
        this.form.value.name,
        this.form.value.surname,
        this.form.value.email,
        this.form.value.phone
    ]
    
    this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Creating request...'
    }).then(loadingElement => {
      loadingElement.present();
      
      this.requestsService.addRequest(
        'something',
        this.form.value.issue,
        this.form.value.place,
        this.form.value.building,
        this.form.value.floor,
        this.form.value.room,
        this.form.value.description,
        this.form.value.heading,
        'pending',
        currentUser,
        new Date(Date.now()),
      ).subscribe(()=> {
        this.dexieService.addRequestToLocalDb(this.form.value, currentUser)
        loadingElement.dismiss();
        this.form.reset()
        this.initUser();
      })
    })
  
  }
```

I want to display data in other form, where the item is clicked from the list of records:

```
   ngOnInit() {
        
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
 
        this.requestId = params.get('uuid');
        this.subscription = this.requestsService.getRequest(this.requestId).pipe(tap( request => {
          console.log(request.user.slice())
        }))
          
    .subscribe(request => {



      return this.form = new FormGroup({
        heading: new FormControl(request.heading, {
          updateOn: 'blur',
        }),
        description: new FormControl(request.description, {
          updateOn: 'blur',
        }),
        name: new FormControl(request.user.name, {
          updateOn: 'blur',
        }),
        surname: new FormControl(null, {
          updateOn: 'blur',
        }),
        email: new FormControl(null, {
          updateOn: 'blur',
        }),
        phone: new FormControl(null, {
          updateOn: 'blur',
        }),
        approverName: new FormControl('approvalManager', {
          updateOn: 'submit'
        }),
        approverSurname: new FormControl('approvalManager', {
          updateOn: 'submit'
        }),
        groupControl: new FormControl(null, {
          updateOn: 'submit',
        }),
        arbeitsplatz: new FormControl(null, {
          updateOn: 'submit'
        }),
        priority: new FormControl(null, {
          updateOn: 'submit'
        })
    });

       })
    

  })
```

but anytime I try to touch request.user.name or request.user['name'], it gets bunch of errors with the form controls. When I console log request.user, it clearly says what is it there, but after I try to display it in my template directly, i get this errors[image]

might somebody help me with that ?

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz for your problem?

Comment: You are missing the template in your example

Comment: Looking at the error messages, at [this line in the FormGroupDirective source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts#L140), the `addControl()` method is calling `this.form.get()`. So your error message `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` hints that `this.form` is probably undefined. In FormGroupDirective, `this.form` is the FormGroup passed to the directive in the template, so you might not be passing your FormGroup to the `formGroup` directive, like this: `<form [formGroup]="profileForm">`.

Comment: hey Mike, what others options do I have ? The thing is, it was never breaking because of the accesing array inside an object. I mean literally everytime I try to acces this array, wherever in code, I got the error.

Comment: @RejzozroutkoTezbir, since `this.form` is not assigned until the `route.paramMap` Observable emits, you can try adding an `*ngIf="form"` to the `div` that references it, like this: `<div *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" >`. If that doesn't fix it, it would be helpful if you could put together a StackBlitz or something that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So problem solved by switching from `FormGroup` to `FormBuilder` method, where I simply could use reference to index in an array `request.user[0]`

The **TS** file of the template **Form initialization**

```
    return this.form = this.fb.group({


 heading: (request.heading),
  description: (request.description),
  approverName: ('hans'),
  approverSurname: ('fajo'),
  groupControl: (null),
  arbeitsplatz: (null),
  priority: (null),
  name: (request.user[0]),
  surname: (request.user[1]),
  email: (request.user[2]),
  phone: (request.user[3])});
```

Thank you **@MikeJ** as well, your solution clear some errors, unfortunately I'm not really sure what happened, but `FormBuilder` method solves the problem.